# How to display the parent Row with Rows at the same position regardless of screens in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

So, I have created a 3 various screens that has a parent along with it's child Rows. Above it I have content in Text, The content in all the screens vary in size, so, when the content is large, the Rows stay down like this [image]

As you can see in first screen, but when I move to middle screen, it changes it's position and get's displayed little up than prior screen, and when I go to 3rd screen, it drastically gets displayed up. I want the position of the parent Row to be exactly same in all screens regardless of the size of content, like shown in the picture. Below is the code of my first screen

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTransformGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Spacer
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.width
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentHeight
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.FractionalThreshold
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.rememberSwipeableState
import androidx.compose.material.swipeable
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontFamily
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextFieldValue
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import com.example.speechrecognition.Destinations
import kotlin.math.absoluteValue

@Composable
fun SpeechScreen1(navController: NavController) {
    var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
    val swipeThreshold = 200 // Adjust this threshold as needed

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(top = 69.dp)) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
                .padding(start = 21.dp, top = 13.dp, end = 25.dp)
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectTransformGestures { _, offset, _, _ ->
                        offsetX += offset.x
                        if (offsetX.absoluteValue >= swipeThreshold) {
                            if (offsetX > 0) {

navController.navigate(Destinations.speechscreen2)
                            }
                            offsetX = 0f
                        }
                    }
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Please read the following text:",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    lineHeight = 28.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(400),
                    color = Color(0xFF000000)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier.height(28.dp).fillMaxWidth()
            )
            Text(
                text = "One morning Dorothy crossed the hall of the
palace and knocked on the door of another girl named Trot. When told
to enter, Dorothy found that Trot had company, an old sailor-man with
a wooden leg who was sitting by the open window puffing smoke from a
pipe.",
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 32.sp,
                    lineHeight = 40.sp,
                    fontFamily = FontFamily.SansSerif,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight(300),
                    color = Color(0xFF080808)
                ),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .padding(top = 9.dp, end = 25.dp)
            )
        }
  
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 27.dp)
            .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()) {
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFF686868))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(77.dp)
                    .height(7.dp)
                    .background(color = Color(0xFFD9D9D9))
                    .padding(top = 26.dp)
            ) {
            }
        }


    }
    }
```

This is same code for other two screens to , only the content of Text is changed.

Comment: So do you want to the text block to always be centered vertically in the screen? I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve, the screenshots look fine to me.

Comment: I want the Rows [one grey and 3 white ] from first screen to  be at the same position regardless of how much content will be in next screens, as you can see they never change the position.

Comment: @TejasKhartude You should share the preview how it looks in your device so that its easy for us to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Change the topmost `Column` Composable as follows:

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().padding(top = 69.dp),
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    //....
}
```

Alternatively you can try to add a `Spacer` Composable with weight that always pushes the four horizontal lines to the bottom of the screen like this:

```
Column(
    // ....
    Text(
        text = "One morning Dorothy ...",
        // ...
    )
)
Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))  // this pushes content downwards
Row(modifier = Modifier
    .padding(top = 27.dp)
    .padding(start = 21.dp, end = 6.dp)
    .fillMaxWidth()) {
        // ...
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/modifiers#weight-in-row-and-column) for `Modifier.weight()`.

Comment: Nope when I add it, All the rows disappeear

Comment: @TejasKhartude See my edited answer. I changed my initial answer and also added a new approach. If both don't work either, then I have no idea,